# An error has occured: Error-unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play porperly and results man not be recorded

Tags: ionic-framework

i am trying to load the html  content in ionic app.
but i am getting lms error An error has occurred: Error-unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play properly at same time when i am trying to load using postman it is working .